# Liferay / EHCache Clustering

Tags: liferay, cluster-computing, ehcache, multicast, rackspace

I am trying to cluster my liferay 6.1.1 CE portal on two servers at Rackspace. The servers are windows 2008 R2, next generation cloud servers. I mention that because for multicasting to work, I have to enable a cloud network at rackspace and attach it to only next generation servers.

Each server has three network interfaces: public, rackspace data center, local private (cloud network).

I have followed all the steps to the tee from multiple articles, but for some reason it just does not want to replicate the data cache between the two servers.

The apache/tomcat configuration for session replication works fine. It also uses multicasting.

I have enabled the following lines in the portal properties file:

cluster.link.enabled=true

cluster.link.autodetect.address=: ---- I added this because it looks like it tries to bind to the public interface if I don't set a local address here...

lucene.replicate.write=true

Another thing here is that we have this exact setup working perfectly in our sandbox environment. The only difference is that the sandbox is not at rackspace, but here locally in our office...

Please help!

Thanks
Wessel

***So multicasting at rackspace does work, if you have next generation servers with a private cloud network attached.  For this liferay clustering to work though, you have to use jgroups instead of RMI.***

## **The lines below is what's needed in your portal properties file to get jgroups cache replication working on rackspace windows servers.  The default RMI replication does not work:**

cluster.link.enabled=true

cluster.link.autodetect.address=[local network IP]:[port]

ehcache.bootstrap.cache.loader.factory=com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.JGroupsBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory

ehcache.cache.event.listener.factory=net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheReplicatorFactory

ehcache.cache.manager.peer.provider.factory=net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory

lucene.replicate.write=true

**Also add the following line to your setenv.bat as part of your JVM startup options:**

-Djgroups.bind_addr=[local network IP]

Comment: I'm going to spin up some servers to test.

Comment: Are you spinning them up at Rackspace?

Comment: Yes. I work at Rackspace as a Developer Support Engineer. I'm replicating your Liferay setup currently. To follow-up, both of your servers are in the same datacenter, correct? And the IP address you've set for cluster.link.autodetect.address is that of the network you created and attached to the 2 servers?

Comment: Yes sir.  Both are in the ORD datacenter.  And yes the address is for the local cloud network

Comment: Also to note, I also have a portlet inside Liferay which also uses EHCache with RMI replication with multicast.  It's the same as the Liferay cache, where for some reason it's just not replicating...

Comment: Hey JRP, have perhaps made any progress with this?  I also have a ticket open at rackspace that has been escalated to the network engineers, if you would like to look at it...

Comment: I'm still working on it. There's quite a bit of domain-specific knowledge that I'm trying to learn to make sure I have things configured correctly. I'll be working on it for the rest of today (and tomorrow if need be). I also looked at your Rackspace ticket and am monitoring it for any developments.

Comment: Hey JRP, have you had any luck with this?

Comment: I was able to create a cluster of 3 Ubuntu servers and have the ehcache replication working. I created a Cloud Network similar to yours and used the network IP from the server with my MySQL instance as the cluster.link.autodetect.address parameter (namely, cluster.link.autodetect.address=192.168.3.3:22). So I can confirm that multicast is working. Can you confirm that multicast packets are reaching your servers? Also, what is your tomcat installation path?

Comment: Not sure if the difference has to do with Ubuntu vs Windows then, as I have windows servers.  I did change my tomcat installation path to have no spaces, which I'm assuming is what your question refers to, but that did not work.  However, if you setup the replication using JGroups, it does work, which I just figured out a few minutes ago.  The default RMI replication configuration does not seem to work in Rackspace on windows servers, but JGroups does work....

Comment: Do you know what the difference in functionality between RMI and JGroups could be causing this?

Comment: You're correct. It may be a Windows vs Linux issue. To start, I was just trying to ascertain whether it was a Cloud Networks multicasting issue or not, which it doesn't seem to be. I don't know enough about RMI or JGroups to speak to their differences, but it does look like the Linux version uses JGroups by default. Here are 3 relevant lines from my log file: [Autodetecting JGroups outgoing IP address and interface for 192.168.3.3:22], [Setting JGroups outgoing IP address to 192.168.3.4 and interface to eth2], [Accepted view (liferay1-24795) (liferay1-24795, liferay3-21205, liferay2-7240)]

Comment: After a brief search, it looks like RMI uses tcp (whereas JGroups uses UDP). http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/ehcache-replication-rmi-vs-jgroups.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specifically "introduce" the nodes to each other they will try to discover each other through multicast. My bet is that Rackspace is not routing any multicast requests. Look at the JGroups configuration where you can have your cluster machines communicate through unicast and it should work, given proper connectivity (try ping first)

You'll have to set the autodetect address, because that's the mechanism that determines which interface the (multicast) requests will be sent out on. As you obviously don't want them on your public-facing interface, it's correct (and expected) that you configure it.

Comment: Thanks Olaf.  Actually Rackspace claims that multicasting should be working with the "cloud network".  Essentially it creates a layer 2 software network, isolated from the other networks.  They implemented this for multicasting purposes, among other things.  Any thoughts on why the tomcat session replication works perfectly with multicasting, but not liferay cache replication?

Comment: from the top of my head, what's in the answer is the low hanging fruit that almost always fixes the problem. If this doesn't help in your case, it's hard to do distance-diagnostic. You did set the clusterlink autodetect address, right? (because your setting above has it empty). Also, check what the logfile contains - it should give you hints if there's anything it detects

Comment: Yes sir I did set that address to a local address.  Sorry I left it blank.  I have set the following logging in the log4j.properties file.

Comment: log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache=INFO
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache.config=DEBUG
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache.distribution=DEBUG

Comment: This creates an enormous amount of logging and is hard to filter through.  But it does look like the multicast is communicating from what I can see.  But still the caches are not replicating...

Comment: I finally tried JGroups, and that does seem to work.  The default RMI replication does not work on rackspace windows servers.  The items below is what is required in the portal properties file to enable jgroups:

Comment: Actually I will update my original question with jgroups configuration